# Change the height of a row after the Ui has been displayed

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, monotouch.dialog, textkit

In monotouch.dialog is it possible to alter the height of a row after the Ui has been displayed?

The reason for this is that the UI is drawn and then once some text is passed back from a service I am populating a TextViewElement which uses Text Kit to draw the text to the Ui.

I want to resize the row to fit the text.

I am using IElementSizing but this is only called on first load. I need to modify the row height after this.

I have also set uneven rows on the root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IElement.GetHeight` should be called again after you call `Reload`, e.g.

```
root_element.Reload (your_element, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
```

Note: it's easier to answer (and likely more accurate) when you provide some source code about what you're using (or tried).